# Return True/False from a mysql array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this query here:

```
function movement_performed_today($class_id, $client_id){
$class_id = (int)$class_id;
$client_id = (int)$client_id;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`movement`) FROM `completed_movements` WHERE `class_id` = '$class_id' AND `client_id` = '$client_id' AND `date` = CURDATE()");

$movement_performed = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

print_r($movement_performed);   
}
```

That returns this:

```
Array ( 
[COUNT(`movement`)] => 0 
) 
Array ( 
[COUNT(`movement`)] => 0 
)
```

Which is correct. Now I want to do something like this:

```
function movement_performed_today($class_id, $client_id){
$class_id = (int)$class_id;
$client_id = (int)$client_id;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`movement`) FROM `completed_movements` WHERE `class_id` = '$class_id' AND `client_id` = '$client_id' AND `date` = CURDATE()");

$movement_performed = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

return (mysql_result($movement_performed['count'], 0) == 1) ? true : false; 
}
```

So that I can call this function inside of a while loop and if it returns 0/false it will then post the form data to the db. Can someone help? Here is the while loop where Im trying to perform this function:

```
if (empty($_POST)=== false){
$i = 0;
while (isset($_POST["first_name"][$i])) {
    $movement_data = array(   
    'user_id'       => $session_user_id,   
    'class_id'      => $class_id,   
    'class_name'    => $class_name,
    'client_id'     => $_POST['client_id'][$i],    
    'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'][$i],   
    'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'][$i],   
    'nickname'      => $_POST['nickname'][$i],   
    'order'         => $_POST['order'][$i],   
    'movement'      => $_POST['movement'][$i],   
    'rep_set_sec'   => $_POST['rep_set_sec'][$i],   
    'rest'          => $_POST['rest'][$i],   
    'date'          => $today   
    );  

   $movement_performed = movement_performed_today($class_id, $_POST['client_id']);
   foreach ($movement_performed as $performed){
   if($performed == false){
    completed_movement($movement_data);
    } // if performed
  } // foreach
   $i++; 
   } // while

} // if empty
```

Comment: Insert bowel joke here.  Seriously though, Should probably look at enforcing uniqueness with database constraints.  Can still do the SELECT COUNT check but ensure that any race conditions are handled properly once trying to insert to DB.  Can you explain what you mean by "for a single form but not an array"?

Comment: The parsing scripts loops through rows in a form and inserts each row of data in db with each row of data in the form representing a new row of data in the db. So when I do my check I need to see if the $_POST['movement'] in each row has already been posted in the db and if so go to the next row in the array. Does that make sense?

Comment: So do the same thing but in a loop?  Just need to make your call to `movement_performed_today` in the loop before each insert no?

Comment: Please **DO NOT USE** `mysql_query` in new applications. It's being phased out of PHP. You should be using `mysqli` or PDO for all new code. Clever tricks like casting to `int` are no substitute for [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). If you develop bad habits like that, one day you will make a mistake, and those can cost you dearly.

Comment: I edited my parsing script to call my function but its not working. It seems to be just getting stuck. I've tried to echo back variables in the loop just to see what I was getting, but no such luck. Evidently I'm not doing something right here.

Comment: @tadman I am aware of PDO I began building this using mysql_query and I have planned on keeping that way until complete and then going back and changing them all at that time.

Comment: @ficuscr Im at a loss I have tried call my function before the `$movement_data = array` and afterwards with now luck. Every time I attempt to call the function inside the while loop it breaks the page. Any thoughts as to what Im doing wrong?

Comment: @tadman Im pretty green at this so this may sound dumb but what do you mean by casting to `int`?

Comment: That's what `(int)` does. It converts (or casts) to an integer instead of an arbitrary string.

Comment: @tadman What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: @tadman I have edited my question and code to simplify what Im trying to do. Can either of you help me out?

Comment: @ficuscr I have edited my question and code to simplify what Im trying to do. Can you take a look at and tell me what I need to do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your method `movement_performed_today` returns a Boolean.  Not something you can loop on.  Do the check in your main loop.  Also you are aware that trusting user input from a _POST is not secure?  The use of mysql_query is depreciated you need to look at using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and bound parameters.

```
if (! empty($_POST)) {
    $i = 0;
    while (isset($_POST["first_name"][$i])) {
        $movement_data = array(   
        'user_id'       => $session_user_id,   
        'class_id'      => $class_id,   
        'class_name'    => $class_name,
        'client_id'     => $_POST['client_id'][$i],    
        'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'][$i],   
        'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'][$i],   
        'nickname'      => $_POST['nickname'][$i],   
        'order'         => $_POST['order'][$i],   
        'movement'      => $_POST['movement'][$i],   
        'rep_set_sec'   => $_POST['rep_set_sec'][$i],   
        'rest'          => $_POST['rest'][$i],   
        'date'          => $today);  

        //check not already performed today
        $isPerformed = movement_performed_today($class_id, $_POST['client_id']);

        //if not performed then do insert
        if(! $isPerformed) completed_movement($movement_data);    

        $i++; 
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So how does my query need to change so that if it returns 1/true it will skip the `completed_movement` function?

Comment: thanks for your help. Does my query need to change to make this operate properly?